# Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined Express js MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to add authentication to my ionic application  but I get this error that I don't know how to solve it: `Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined`
I want to check about the user if he exists in the database or not but for some reason, I get this error when I try the login in postman

please what I'm missing?

here the auth.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const _ = require("lodash");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const joi = require('joi');
const { DRAFBIE } = require('../employees/drafbie');

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    
    let user = await DRAFBIE.findOne({ DECAFFE: req.body.DECAFFE})
    if (!user) {
        return res.send("employee number is wrong");
    }
    const checkpassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.MOT_PASS, user.MOT_PASS);
    if (!checkpassword) {
        return res.send("Invalid password");
    }
    res.send("welcome to your account")
});



module.exports = router;
```

here the drafbie.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const DRAFBIE = mongoose.model("DRAFBIE", mongoose.Schema({
    DECAFFE: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        minlength: [3, 'the min value is 100'],
        maxlength: [5, "the max value is 9999"]
    },
    DELAFFE: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    TYPE: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 1
    },
    AR_DELAFFE: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    VLD: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        max:[1,"the value of the VLD must be 0 or 1 "]
    },
    MOT_PASS:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    DEMAIL: {
        type: String,
    },
    NATURE: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: 1
    }

}))
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const drafbie = await DRAFBIE.find().sort("DECAFFE");
    res.send(drafbie);
});
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const drafbie = new DRAFBIE({
        DECAFFE: req.body.DECAFFE,
        DELAFFE: req.body.DELAFFE,
        TYPE: req.body.TYPE,
        AR_DELAFFE: req.body.AR_DELAFFE,
        VLD: req.body.VLD,
        MOT_PASS: req.body.MOT_PASS,
        DEMAIL: req.body.DEMAIL,
        NATURE:req.body.NATURE
    })
    await drafbie.save();
    res.send(drafbie);
})
router.put("/:decaffe&:password", async (req, res) => {
    const saltRound = 10;

    const drafbie = await DRAFBIE.findOneAndUpdate({ DECAFFE: req.params.decaffe },
        {
            $set: {
                MOT_PASS: await bcrypt.hash(req.params.password,saltRound)
        }
    },{new:true}
    )
    await drafbie.save();
    res.send(drafbie)
})

async function updateallpassword() {
    const saltRound = 10;
    const drafbie = await DRAFBIE.updateMany({ MOT_PASS: "123456789" },
        {
            $set: {
                MOT_PASS: await bcrypt.hash("123456789", saltRound)
            }
        } ,{new:true});
    console.log(drafbie + " the update is done successfully");
   }
//updateallpassword();
module.exports = router;
exports.DRAFBIE = DRAFBIE;
```

here the new error when I change :

`module.exports = router; exports.DRAFBIE = DRAFBIE;`

`module.exports.DRAFBIE = DRAFBIE; module.exports.router = router;`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exporting the model in the wrong way.Try to modify the last lines of your `drafbie.js` from :

```
module.exports = router;
exports.DRAFBIE = DRAFBIE;
```

to :

```
module.exports.DRAFBIE = DRAFBIE;
module.exports.router = router; // I modified it to export the router object too, it will impact the code where you import the router.
```

This will allow you to import the DRAFBIE model in the auth.js like you did : `const { DRAFBIE } = require('../employees/drafbie');`

How do you use the routes defined in your drafbie.js file?

Comment: is not working brother when I change `module.exports.DRAFBIE = DRAFBIE;` I got other error ( I will update the post with the index.js with the error when i change the export.DRABIE )

Comment: yeah, it's the problem because i modified how the router is export, you can modify : `const drafbie = require("./employees/drafbie");` to `const {router : drafbie } = require("./employees/drafbie");` in your index.js file

Comment: But, it could be better if you can separate the route code  in your drafbie.js file to another file :)

Comment: friend, you are the best it's working now perfectly, and sorry if my code looks ugly this is my first time I try to work backend :)